# convert iphone 5 app to use 3.5inch screen

Tags: ios

i am relatively new to this and i have just launched my first app, when i was filling in the information to launch the app on the dev account i realised that there was another screen size my app would need to fit, i have already completed the app and have made it a 4 inch screen size fitting the iPhone 5 and 5s, how can i make it compatible with the iPhone 4 and 4s? i have checked other questions but i don't really understand it if anyone can just give me a simple answer to this it will be greatly appreciated.

thank you

Comment: Please do some searching. There are plenty of existing discussions on supporting both screen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use [autoresizing masks](http://www.techpaa.com/2012/05/understanding-uiview-autoresizing.html) or [autolayot](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)(constraints).

Comment: I'm sorry to sound nooby but how would i do that.

Comment: I have added few links.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more complicated UI then either use new .xib or Storyboard for 3.5 inch for all classes.

Comment: i used a duplicate to add another storyboard but from here i don't know what to do

Comment: I haven't done this before, but isn't the solution just to add a separate storyboard-file for your iPhone interface? Choose file -> New -> File. Then in the iOS / User Interface section, click on storyboard and hit next. Make sure you choose iPhone as Device Family.

In your iOS Application Target change Devices from iPhone to Universal. Scroll down and select your Storyboard file for your iPhone in the iPhone Deployment Info section.

The rest should be pretty much like making your iPhone app. You'll have to make the iPhone 3.5 UI and connect buttons, make icons, etc.

Comment: More info. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/Miscellaneous/RN-AdoptingStoryboards/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Attribute inspector for view controller have a list "Size". You can select 3.5" to watch out you app appear.